# Is there a way to uniquely identify a web user?

Tags: browser, spam-prevention

I want to identify every anonymous person accessing my web portal uniquely (crazy, I know!). Currently I am using session id in combination with IP, however, since a session id is cookie based, it can always be cleared and identity can be forged. I was browsing some other thread and someone had said that an attribute named "PCRSA" can be obtained from browsers and can be used to uniquely identify a user. Ever since, I've trying to locate any further info regarding PCRSA but to no avail. Does anyone have any info regarding PCRSA or alternatively, a better way to uniquely identify anonymous connections?

Comment: I would use browser fingerprinting in combination with what you are using now. fingerprintjs is an option for now, see https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs, until fingerprintjs2 is ready, see https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2.  Can only find medical references to PCRSA but looks like PC RSA which may refer to MicroSoft's Protected Configuration RSA Key Containers.

Comment: Thanks man! Will explore things on similar lines. Thanks!

Comment: https://webtransparency.cs.princeton.edu/webcensus/
this should be an interesting reading regarding device fingerpriting.